# How to catch child error from parent function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So guys I have 2 functions, the first is named `child Function()`, the second is `parentFunction()`. So I'm trying to get an error from `childFunction()`, where `childFunction()` contains the following code

```
async childFunction() {
  await getFromApi()
}
```

and i tried to call `childFunction()` from `parentFunction()` like this

```
async parentFunction() {
  try {
    await childFunction()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

my expected error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at fetchWith (fetch.browser.js?273a:103:1)
at Client.fetch (http.js?670b:132:1)
at Client.fetch (core.js?0abd:182:1)
at Client.post (http.js?670b:174:1)
at addAll (add-all.js?74f2:31:1)
at async last (index.js?9975:13:1)
at async Object.add (add.js?59bb:18:1)
```

but I don't get any error or console. So the error can only be accessed in `childFunction()` only when I use try-catch in `childFunction()`. Even then I can't send the error to `parentFunction()`. So my question, how to send error from `childFunction()` to `parentFunction()`. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can re-throw the error from the `catch` block in `childFunction()`

Comment: There's no difference in this specific piece of code if try..catch is in childFunction or  parentFunction. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There's no such problem in general, it's specific to something you didn't show. Why is there Vue tag? The question doesn't reflect this.

Comment: Hi @lbsn I've tried that way, but still not showing any error or even console

Comment: @DickiMaulana Please add more details. Are the functions in the same Vue component or in different ones? What is `getFromApi()` doing? What error are you expecting to get?

Comment: @lbsn updated question, btw i tried to add/post file to IPFS